# "No se pudo encontrar el control 'DropCiudad' en ControlParameter 'CodigoCiudad'."

Tags: sql-server, asp.net

Contexto: Deseo anidar dos ddl(dropdownlist de mi Gridview. Mi primer ddl es DropCiudad y el segundo ddl es DropComuna.Lo que intento realizar es que dependiendo de la ciudad que eliga cambie las comunas que alberga esa dicha ciudad.
Tener en cuenta que el ddl se encuentra dentro de EditItemTemplate.

El error que surge cuando quiero entrar a la pagina donde esta el grid:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi Gridview "GridLectores":

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridLectores" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" DataKeyNames="CODLIB,PAR_COD_PAR" CssClass="gridview" Style="margin-left: 100px" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="0" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="Horizontal" PageSize="5" Width="50%" Height="270px" HorizontalAlign="Center" CellSpacing="1" OnRowUpdating="Actualizar_Lectores" OnRowDeleting="Borrar_Lector" OnRowDataBound="GridLectores_RowDataBound">
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Ciudad" SortExpression="Ciudad">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropCiudad" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceCiudad" DataValueField="PAR_COD_PAR" DataTextField="PAR_DES_PAR"></asp:DropDownList>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label11" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Ciudad") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Comuna" SortExpression="Comuna">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropComuna" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceComuna" DataValueField="PAR_COD_PAR" DataTextField="PAR_DES_PAR"></asp:DropDownList>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label10" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Comuna") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Seleccione">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="btnupdate" class="btn btn-info" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Update"
                            Text="Actualizar" Style="padding: 3px 3px 3px 3px"></asp:Button>
                        <asp:Button ID="btnborrar" class="btn btn-danger" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Delete"
                            Text="Borrar" Style="padding: 3px 3px 3px 3px"></asp:Button>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="btncancelar" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel"
                            Text="Cancelar" CssClass="BotonRojo" Style="padding: 3px 3px 3px 3px; margin-top: 3px"></asp:LinkButton>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="btnedit" class="btn btn-primary" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Edit"
                            Text="Editar" Style="padding: 3px 3px 3px 3px"></asp:LinkButton>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Mis SqlDatasource:

```
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceComuna" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:CadenaConexion %>" SelectCommand="SELECT par_cod_par, par_des_par, par_cod_aux FROM PAR WHERE (par_cod_tab = 2) AND (par_cod_aux = @CodigoCiudad)">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropCiudad" PropertyName="SelectedValue" DefaultValue="0" Name="CodigoCiudad"></asp:ControlParameter>
            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceCiudad" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:CadenaConexion %>" SelectCommand="SELECT par_cod_tab, par_cod_par, par_des_par FROM PAR WHERE (par_cod_tab = 4) ORDER BY PAR_COD_PAR ASC"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Si pueden orientarme a que es lo que no estoy viendo, o que me esta faltando por favor. Toda ayuda es bienvenida, gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías usar JavaScript y un [HiddenField](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hiddenfield?view=netframework-4.8) para almacenar el id de la ciudad y llenar el ddl comuna.

Función JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            function SetIdCiudad(ddl) {
                //ddl.value
                alert('Selected Value = ' + ddl.value);
                document.getElementById('HiddenField_idCiudad').value = ddl.value;
        }
        </script>
```

Cód HTML:

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Ciudad">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList_Ciudad" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList_Ciudad_SelectedIndexChanged"
                            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource_Ciudad" DataTextField="Ciudad" DataValueField="Id" onChange="SetIdCiudad(this);">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
```

Al momento de llenar el DDL comuna, le pasas como parámetro el id de la ciudad (hiddenfield.value)